# Allow a regular user to mount VeraCrypt volume without admin privileges

Tags: permissions, mount, sudo, security, veracrypt

A regular user is unable to mount a VeraCrypt volume without first authenticating with an administrator password. According to the original TrueCrypt documentation, the workaround is to give the user `sudo` privileges on the `veracrypt` directory.

> Edit visudo and add `USERNAME ALL = (root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/veracrypt`

[Source = Method 2 here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TrueCrypt#Mount_volumes_as_a_normal_user)

This is insecure and opens up doors for vulnerabilities at the root level.

Source: [Is it secure to mount VeraCrypt without sudo password in this way | Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178610/is-it-secure-to-mount-veracrypt-without-sudo-password-in-this-way)

How can a regular user **safely** mount a VeraCrypt container without needing the administrator password or having `sudo` privileges?

Or is it actually safe to add the above to visudo?

Comment: I don’t believe it’s possible to safely allow non-root users to mount veracrypt containers without changing the way that veracrypt mounts filesystems.

Comment: I have not been able to find a solution. Files are secure in the Veracrypt container, but using the recommended procedure to allow users to mount the volume makes the entire device vulnerable. Seems to defeat the purpose. I'm determined to find a way to do this safely.